# Animation on CSV array changes

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, csv, animation

I have a simple page that displays race results. The results are pulled from a CSV file which updates upon completion of each race. The changes could be subtle so would like to have an animation, fade in/out or colour change etc, only if results are different. I want to add a  to the table **ONLY** if the CSV file has new results as a visual aid to the update.

**EDIT**: I am unsure where to start on implementation so no code is reflected below. The CSV is scanned every 1 second and table updated. The outcome I want is for the table results to have an animation if/when array results change, else no animation.

**EDIT 2**: I have attempted to output the current racer number from the results data ($csv[1]) to a file and then check that against the current race number but it doesn't seem to work. When I pull $lastrace[0] and $csv[1] they are always the same number. I thought having it higher in the PHP would get $lastrace before writing the new number but doesn't appear so.

```
// Get Racer No from previous race
$lastrace = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('lastraceno.txt'));

// Puts current racer no to CSV file
$file = fopen("lastraceno.txt","w");
fputcsv($file,explode(',',$csv[1]));
fclose($file);
```

My code as it stands is as below - have trimmed some irrelevant code.

**index.php**

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('table.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body background="timebg.jpg">
   <div id="tableHolder"></div>
</body>
```

**table.php**

```
<?php
$f_pointer=fopen("csv.txt","r"); // file pointer
while(! feof($f_pointer)){
$csv=fgetcsv($f_pointer);

   foreach($csv as &$val){
   if($val === "" || $val === false || $val === null) $val = "NA";
   }

}
?>
<table>
   <tr>
      <td><?php echo $csv[2] ?> <?php echo $csv[3]?></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What is your exact question? What have you tried to reach your goal? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I have not tried any code as I don't know where to start with animations. I want the table to have an animation of some sort when the results from the CSV file change. I am thinking an if else statement on array results would work but not sure on implementation.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

The racer number is $csv[1](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) in my Array from the results file. I found writing the $csv[1](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to a new CSV file and comparing $csv[1](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) to $lastrace[0] each refresh to work.

Using an if else statement I compared the info and set a variable depending if there was a match or not.If the data matched the variable is '0' and no action is required. If $csv[1](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) did not match $lastrace[0] the variable is '1' and the new race number sent to the lastraceno.txt for future updates.

I could then set a CSS class based on if the variable was 0 or 1.

CSS animation achieved with [https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/]Animate.CSS[1](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

**index.php**

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      refreshTable();
    });

    function refreshTable(){
        $('#tableHolder').load('table.php', function(){
           setTimeout(refreshTable, 1000);
        });
    }
</script>
</head>
<body background="timebg.jpg">
   <div id="tableHolder"></div>
</body>
```

**table.php**

```
<?php
$f_pointer=fopen("csv.txt","r"); // file pointer
while(! feof($f_pointer)){
$csv=fgetcsv($f_pointer);
}

// Replace blank lines with NA
foreach($csv as &$val){
if($val === "" || $val === false || $val === null) $val = "NA";
}

// Get Racer No from previous race
$lastrace = str_getcsv(file_get_contents('lastraceno.txt'));

// Puts current racer no to CSV file
if ($lastrace[0]==="$csv[1]") {
$newrace = 0; // This is not a new race
} else {
$newrace = 1; // This is a new race
$file = fopen("lastraceno.txt","w");
fputcsv($file,explode(',',$csv[1]));
fclose($file);
}

if ($newrace == '1') {
$newtimes = "class='animated zoomIn'";
} else { }

<table <?php echo $newtimes ?>>
   <tr>
   <td>Text to animate</td>
   </tr>
</table.
```